# Neither loud nor quiet volume level

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word that can describe a level of volume that is neither loud nor quiet. Say for example you go into a classroom and people are talking. It's not so loud that people are yelling at each other but it's not so quiet that they're all whispering either. It's just at a normal conversational level.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps:

> [Audible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/audible)
>
> *heard or capable of being heard*

or,

> [Leveled](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leveled), as in level:
>
> *the magnitude of a quantity considered in relation to an arbitrary reference value*

or,

> [Intelligible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intelligible)
>
> *capable of being understood or comprehended*

or,

> [Mild](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mild)
>
> *moderate in action or effect*

But I think that if you use the common conversational words without specifying anything outside the normal (too loud, too quiet) it should work fine: [Gab](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gab), [Chat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chat), [Converse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/converse), etc.

Comment: I think mild is the word I'm looking for.

Comment: Very few native English speakers would use *mild* to refer to this kind of volume.

Answer (score 0):

How about "Moderate"?
like moderately loud/quiet, moderately toned, moderate volume, etc.